# How to Handle Rows that Change over Time in Druid

Tags: druid

I'm wondering how we could handle data that changes over time in Druid. I realize that Druid is built for streaming data where we wouldn't expect a particular row to have data elements change. However, I'm working on a project where we want to stream transactional data from a logistics management system, but there's a calculation that happens in that system that can change for a particular transaction based on other transactions. What I mean:

-9th of the month - I post transaction A with a date of today (9th) that results in the stock on hand coming to 0 units

-10th of the month - I post transaction B with a date of the 1st of the month, crediting my stock amount by 10 units. At this time (on the 10th of the month) the stock on hand for transaction A recalculates to 10 units. The same would be true for ALL transactions after the 1st of the month

As I understand it, we would re-extract transaction A, resulting in transaction A2.

The stock on hand dimension is incredibly important to our metrics. Specifically, identifying when stockouts occur (when stock on hand = 0). In the above example, if I have two rows for transaction A, I would be mistakenly identifying a stockout with transaction A1, whereas transaction A2 is the source of truth.

Is there any ability to archive a row and replace it with an updated row, or do we need to add logic to our queries that finds the rows with the freshest timestamp per transaction id?

Thanks

Comment: Hey Clay, did you try any solution to implement this? I am looking for a solution for a similar use case.

Answer (score 1):

I have two thoughts that I hope help you.  The key documentation for this is "Updating Existing Data": http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/update-existing-data.html which gives you three options: Lookup Tables, Reindexing, and Delta Ingestion.  The last one, Delta Ingestion, is only for adding new rows to old segments, so that's not very useful for you, let's go over the other two.

Reindexing: You can crunch all the numbers that change in your ETL process, identify the segments that would need to be reloaded, and simply have Druid re-index those segments.  That will replace the stock-on-hand value for A in your example whenever you want, whenever you do the re-indexing.

Lookups: If you have stock values for multiple products, you can store the product id in the segment and have that be immutable, but lookup the stock-on-hand value in a lookup.  So, you would store:

```
A, 2018-01-01, product-id: 123
```

And in your lookup, you'd have:

```
product-id: 123, stock-on-hand: 0
```

And later, you'd update the lookup and change that to 10.  This would update any rows that reference product-id: 123.

I can't be sure but you may be mixing up dimensions and metrics while you're doing this, and you may need to read over that terminology in OLAP descriptions like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing

Good luck!